# How to have The Old Reader show more than the 10 first items of my RSS feed

Tags: the-old-reader

I'm trying to subscribe to the Biophysical Journal RSS feed via [The Old Reader](http://www.theoldreader.com/).

There are a couple of RSS sources to work with (curiously, but not related to this question directly, [the feed by Cell.com](http://www.cell.com/biophysj/current.rss) doesn't show the latest issue, but [the one from MedWorm](http://www.medworm.com/rss/search.php?qu=Biophysical+Journal&t=Biophysical+Journal&s=Search&f=source) and [the one I created via a PubMed search](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/erss.cgi?rss_guid=1B3BG_B5Yy7ac8xfdwXWhEm-avEWdtLViVrjPX9JaESMMWycGh) do).

But when I add any of those to The Old Reader, I only see the top ten items, even though there are 20 in the Cell.com one, and 50 in the PubMed one. This actually happens in [Feedly](http://www.feedly.com/) too.

Other feeds, such as [Scientific Reports](http://www.nature.com/srep/rss/latest), show up entirely.

How can I get The Old Reader to recognize more than the top 10 items for the Biophysical Journal as well?

Comment: I have a feeling that The Old Reader only shows items for 30 days - could that be the problem?   If it is, the I think the only fix is to move to another RSS reader (I went to inoreader)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote The Old Reader and got their reply:

> When you first subscribe to a feed, we only fetch the last 10 items. Going forward, we will collect all new posts in the feed.
>
> There is no way to change this. However, if the feed was previously in our system before you subscribed, we may already have the last 50 items. If you click the "Show All Posts" button, you can see all of the posts for this feed that we have in the system.

So that's the end of that.